# Python / numpy: How to replace matrix elements with specified length along axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that specifies how many elements along the last axis of a matrix I want to change to 0. How do I do this efficiently?

```
x = np.ones((4, 4, 10))
change_to_zeros = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4))
# change_to_zeros = 
# [[2 1 6 8]
# [4 0 4 8]
# [7 6 6 2]
# [4 0 7 1]]
```

Now what I want to do is something like `x[:, :, :change_to_zeros] = 0` - for example for the first element of `change_to_zeros`, I have `change_to_zeros[0, 0] = 2` so I want to change the first (or last, or whatever) 2 elements along the last axis of x (length 10) to 0.

Clarification: For example at `x[0, 0, :]` I have ones with length 10. I want to change 2 of these (`change_to_zeros[0, 0] = 2`) to 0, keeping the rest with ones.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what your intended output must be

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. For example at `x[0, 0, :]` I have ones with length 10. I want to change 2 of these (`change_to_zeros[0, 0] = 2`) to 0, keeping the rest with ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a boolean array (*same shape as `x`*) with `change_to_zeros[:,:,None] > np.arange(x.shape[-1])` and then assign zero to *true*s:

```
x[change_to_zeros[:,:,None] > np.arange(x.shape[-1])] = 0
```

Check results:

```
change_to_zeros[0,0]
# 2

x[0,0]
# array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

change_to_zeros[0,2]
# 7

x[0,2]
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```